# Получить информация о статусе базы данных

Tags: yii, отладка

Мне нужно выполнить команду show innodb status, когда случается в моем приложении исключение с классом CDbExcepton (YII). Я определил свой класс DbException и унаследовал его от CDbException. И замапил его через Yii::$classMap. И это работает, до тех пор, пока что-то плохое не случается с самой базой. Тогда вызов CDbException зацикливаеться.
Как лучше всего вписать в архитектуру YII такой функционал? Думал еще определить свой log route который бы делал этот дополнительный запрос и перехватывал исключение, но такой роут не будет гибким, напримр, он будет только на почту слать.

index.php

```
Yii::$classMap['CDbException'] = 'protected/components/DbException.php';
```

DbException.php

```
class DbException extends CException
{
    /**
     * @var mixed the error info provided by a PDO exception. This is the same as returned
     * by {@link http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php PDO::errorInfo}.
     * @since 1.1.4
     */
    public $errorInfo;
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param string $message PDO error message
     * @param integer $code PDO error code
     * @param mixed $errorInfo PDO error info
     */
    public function __construct($message,$code=0,$errorInfo=null)
    {
        $this->errorInfo=$errorInfo;
        if(!isset(Yii::app()->db) || strpos($message, "Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation.")) {
            $message .= PHP_EOL . 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS : no DB connection or access error';
        } else {
            // сама по себе createCommand() бросает исключение CDbException и чтобы не
            // возникло рекурсии бесконечной, мы перехватываем исключение и гасим его
            try {
                $status = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS")->queryRow();
                $status = $status['Status'];
                $message .= print_r($status, true);
            } catch (CDbException $ex) {
                $message .= "\n\nCan not execute 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS'";
            }
        }
        parent::__construct($message,$code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам не нужно выполнять никаких команд во время отлова выброшенного исключения, для которого не выставлен отдельный catch. Это неправильно, к тому же, никто не гарантирует, что его причиной не стала отказавшая база данных, что, в свою очередь, вызовет еще одно исключение.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге я реализовал сбор информации о состоянии БД в своем собственном лог роуте